# getting null pointer exception when i click on spinner to select item

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner

I have populated spinner from webservice.The data is added to the adapter and is shown in spinner as i click on spinner.I need to do is i want the selected item from the spinner and then split it and pass the payout number to other webservice.

I am getting null pointer excetion when i add the following code on my OnItemSelectedListener as shown in following code.

Please see my code and help me by telling what i have done wrong :

Code from where i populate spinner :

```
        results = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));
        if (results != null) {
            Log.v("val", results.getString(0));
            for (int i = 0; i <= results.length() - 1; i++) {
                // val[i] = results.getString(i);
                String val1 = results.getString(i);
                val[i] = val1;
                val1 = "";
                Log.v("Val", "[" + i + "]" + results.getString(i));
            }
        } else {
            Log.v("results", "results are null");
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, val);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spn1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Code for OnItemSelectedListener of spinner :

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        String PayoutNo = spnPayout.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Log.v("seleced item", PayoutNo);
        Toast.makeText(PayoutDetailsActivity.this, "selected item is"+PayoutNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("TAG","inside on click");
        //String PayoutNo = spnPayout.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Log.v("selected item",PayoutNo);
        String[] strPayoutNo = new String[15];
        strPayoutNo = PayoutNo.split("-");
        Log.v("TAG",strPayoutNo[0]);
        getPayoutDetails(strPayoutNo[0]);//in this function i am calling another webservice
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Log :

```
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:329)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:325)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout.onMeasure(WeightedLinearLayout.java:60)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-18 12:01:21.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 12:01:21.576: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.biz.mlm/.PayoutDetailsActivity
08-18 12:01:22.163: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{450cdbd8 com.biz.mlm/.PayoutDetailsActivity}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
MyOnItemSelectedListener myOnItemSelectedListener = new MyOnItemSelectedListener();
```

### ---------------------

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, val);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spn1.setAdapter(adapter);
spn1.seOnItemSelectedListener( myOnItemSelectedListener);
```

Comment: declare 'adapter' and 'spn1' as a class variable.